# What is a shell command to find the longest common substring of two strings in unix?

Tags: linux, string, shell, unix, awk

What is a shell command to find the longest common substring of two strings in unix?
like: foo 'abcdefghi' 'abjklmdefnop' 
prints: def

Comment: Does this need to be POSIX? Targeted at any specific distro?

Comment: it's best to have it working on most of linuxes

Comment: @user1081596: Then I recommend implementing this in perl, because it will be installed on every linux unless the user has removed it.

Comment: @user1081596 In this case, why would Perl be a better choice than Ruby, Python, or any other scripting language?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if there is a single command that does the job for you but the following bash script should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

word1="$1"
word2="$2"
if [ ${#word1} -lt ${#word2} ]
then
        word1="$2"
        word2="$1"
fi
for ((i=${#word2}; i>0; i--)); do
        for ((j=0; j<=${#word2}-i; j++)); do
                if [[ $word1 =~ ${word2:j:i} ]]
                then
                        echo ${word2:j:i}
                        exit
                fi
        done
done
```

save the above as a file substr.sh
do chmod +x substr.sh

```
pranithk @ ~
09:24:32 :) $ ./substr.sh 'abcdefghi' 'abcdeghi'
abcde

pranithk @ ~
09:24:33 :) $ ./substr.sh 'abcdefghi' 'abjklmdefnop'
def
```

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the longest common subsequence problem and there are some great algorithms for it. Check out the dynamic programming solution (If you google it, you'll find a ton of implementations). If you really want to understand this at an algorithmic level, check out this MIT lecture,

http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_leiserson_lec15/

Comment: Thank you for this nice link. But for now I am afraid I just need a quick standard command line solution and I would not mind if it is implemented with O(n^5) complexity.

Comment: @user1081596: What size will your inputs be?