# Finding common phrases in text files

Tags: bash, search, sed, grep

I have a large corpus of texts (say, 100 or 150 files) and a new text which I'd like to analyze. I need to know whether it has common phrases or parts of phrases with any text in my corpus (e.g. borrowings, or dependence on a common source). Not knowing how to correctly approach this task, I've developed a procedure, which I cannot call very clever.

1. I make (using a sed script) *pairs*, *threes*, *fours*, *fives* of consecutive words from my file. So, e.g. "threes" will be the file of the following lines

   word1 word2 word3

   word2 word3 word4

   word3 word4 word5
   ...

where word1, word2... are the words of the new file, all the newlines being removed.

2. I grep the files from my corpus, using the lines of the *threes* or *fours* (or even *fives*) files. Then I read grep's output to evaluate which phrases may be borrowings.

So, my question is, how can I make this procedure more effective? Obviously, a borrowing may be not 100% verbatim, I don't know beforehand, how many words were borrowed etc.

UPD: Found this discussion, which seems to be very useful.

[What is a shell command to find the longest common substring of two strings in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383067/what-is-a-shell-command-to-find-the-longest-common-substring-of-two-strings-in-u)

Comment: Suggestions...  Treat the files as sequences of words.  What you're trying to do is the same as finding the longest sub-sequences of size k for the pairs of files.  It's a `O(n^2)` problem.  You may repurpose some of the existing algorithms.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Could you please give me some additional advice as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: And I need not only the longest common sequence, but all significant common sequences.